# WSO2 DSS - How to add response after insert/update query (success or fail)?

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Im using WSO2 DSS and ESB to read database (MySQL) and make an API. Everything is ok but i cant get a response when using insert or update query. How to know that my query is success or fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the wizard you can enable 'Return request status'  on operations screen. In code it would look like this, where you add the returnRequestStatus parameter to your operation.

```
  <operation name="insert_SAMPLEDATA_operation" returnRequestStatus="true">
        <call-query href="insert_SAMPLEDATA_query">
            <with-param name="SAMPLE" query-param="sample"/>
            <with-param name="DATA" query-param="data"/>
        </call-query>
    </operation>
```